# mysql query cache

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL database for an application, but with the increase of records response time has now gone up, so I thought of enabling mysql querycache in my database.
The problem is we often restart the main machine so the query cache becomes 0 all the time. Is there a way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query times are increasing with the number of records, it's time to evaluate table indexes. I would suggest enabling the slow query log and running explain against the slow running queries to figure out where to put indexes. Also please stop randomly restarting your database and fix the root cause instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, yes i should evaluate table indexes, but what i meant of "we often restarts the main machine" is when after a working day we have to shutdown the mechine coz the application is a standalone one,
so... is there a any point of enabling mysql query cache ?? on that mechine, coz after we trun it on next day..  mysql_query_cache becoms 0

Comment: Well, that depends. If you run a single query more than once a day, you'll still benefit from having the query cache enabled. If all queries are unique, then you probably won't.

Comment: Trust me, analyzing slow running queries and fixing them by applying indexes in right places and rewriting poorly written queries will solve your problem. Mysql's query cache isn't very intelligent and will not be helpful with dynamic and transactional queries. If you never run dynamic queries then you try warming the cache as suggested below. I'm not advocating against having a query cache, it's certainly desirable and helpful, but the query cache alone may not be able to solve your problem unless your slow running queries are non-dynamic in nature.

Comment: I fully agree with Sahil here. First make sure your queries are optimized. Then you might want to look at caching.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try warming up cache in startup if you don't mind longer startup time... You can put queries in a separate file (or create a stored procedure that runs a bunch of `selects`, and just call the SP), and then specify path to it in `init_file` parameter of `my.cnf`